# Pass the Protection Status of Excel Worksheet to a Cell

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet, spreadsheet-protection

I'm curious as to whether it's possible to pass the protection status of an excel worksheet to a cell of that worksheet.
e.g.

- Sheet1 is locked for editing...cell `A1` would be programmed to say *"locked"*
- Sheet1 is unlocked...cell `A1` would say *"unlocked"*.

A button on the sheet would be used to toggle worksheet protection on and off.

My sheet will be locked upon opening using a workbook_open event.

This is for a sheet where I don't want the formulae getting all mucked up upon use, but where full access might be required. Its more as a reminder to the user that they are in "Unlocked" Mode so to be extra careful.

Is using VBA a foregone conclusion?

I'm a VBA noob but don't mind using code as a solution for this

Any thoughts or suggestions welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use code in an ActiveX button on Sheet1 to do this simply

```
Const strPAss = "test"

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then
 ActiveSheet.Unprotect strPAss
 [a1].Value = "unlocked"
 Else
 [a1].Value = "locked"
 ActiveSheet.Protect strPAss
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, brettdj - this works to suit my requirements. Does using activex controls have any influence over VBA code that is used with them?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the worksheet's code module, which will place a reminder in the Status Bar (this avoids needing to lock/unlock the sheet in order to write the status in to cell A1).

**Put this in Sheet1 code module.** The macro will execute every time sheet1 is activated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents then
    Application.StatusBar = "This sheet is protected"
Else:
    Application.StatusBar = "This sheet is unprotected"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

**To protect/unprotect the worksheet you could add this to an Insert>Module.**  Then attach these macros to separate command buttons, or run from the Developer>Macros ribbon.

```
Const myPassword as String = "password" '<-- replace "password" with your password

Sub Sht1Protect()
    Sheet1.Protect myPassword
End Sub

Sub Sht1Unprotect()
    Sheet1.Unprotect myPassword
End Sub
```

**To ensure the sheet is always protected when you close the file, insert this in the Workbook code module**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Close()
    Sht1Protect
End Sub
```

You may need additional handling to control whether the file is saved/not saved etc.

Comment: Thanks David - some noob questions...Am i putting this in to the sheet1's code module or going insert>module? I've put it in both and stepped through it in the VBA editor. Can it be linked to a button as a macro or do I use the excel built-in protect worksheet toggle? Can I get it to automatically update to protected/unprotected when done?

Comment: Hi @JohnM, see my revision.

Comment: Thanks David, while this works, for my implementation I'd prefer to be able to format a cell to make it's status more obvious to the user.

Comment: well then brettdj's answer does that. next time it would be nice if you don't send me on a wild goose chase exploring questions/options that you're not actually interested in. cheers.

Comment: Wow. Sorry you feel that way. As a new user to both this site and Excel VBA code I was approaching everything with an open mind and explored your solution in detail to see if it could fit with what I was doing. No offense was intended.

Comment: Next time someone gives you several well-documented code examples, responds to your follow-up queries, is willing to take their time to explore several options for your particular problem, and modifies their answer(s) per your requests, and you find this information in **any** way helpful (even if you ultimately choose a different solution) you might consider **at least** giving their answer an "upvote", for helping you out.

Comment: John no worries, sorry if I came off a little gruff in my previous comment.